# Getting html instead of json respone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am getting a `html` instead of `json` response when i test. Below is code.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AccController, :type => :controller do
  before(:all) do

    user = User.login(FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "test@test.com", password: "test", code: 0));
    if user
      @auth = user['token']
    end
  end

  it "can find an account that this user belongs to" do 
    Account.should_receive(:find, with: {id: 2055, authorization: @auth})

    get :show, id:2055

    hashed_response = {
        "@type" => "test",
        "createdAt" => "2014-08-07T14:31:58.198",
        "createdBy" => 2,
        "updatedAt" => "2014-08-07T14:31:58.247",
        "updatedBy" => 2,
        "accountid" => 2055,
        "name" => "test",
        "description" => "Something about test",
        "disabled" => false
    }

    expect(response.status).to eq 200    
    expect(response.body).to eq(hashed_response.to_json);

  end

end
```

Below is what my rspec is failure message.

```
Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to eq(hashed_response.to_json);      
   expected: "{\"@type\":\"test\",\"createdAt\":\"2014-08-07T14:31:58.198\",\"createdBy\":2,\"updatedAt\":\"2014-08-07T14:31:58.247\",\"updatedBy\":2,\"accountid\":2055,\"name\":\"test\",\"description\":\"Something about test\",\"disabled\":false}"
        got: "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://test.host/login\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
```

I want to check whether my find method yeilds the right response by comparing.

Comment: You should first stub logged in user (as the error message suggests)

Comment: authorization: @auth contains the token...

Comment: And how is it passed to the controller, exactly?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I have updated my entire code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set what type of data you want, otherwise it will return HTML.

```
before :each do
  request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json'
end
```

Comment: I have updated my code... can you check.... your changes still throws the same error.

Comment: How does you controller look?

Comment: what method you are looking in controller?

Comment: The one you're trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the request to

```
xhr(:get, :show, id: "2055", format: "json")
```